# Train and test set have different length of unique target labels

Tags: r, classification, multilabel-classification

I'm trying different algorithms, including a NN for a multiclass sequential classification problem.

Dataset is 66 Bach chorales, 12 binary columns of musical notes, and a target variable "chord", which has 102 unique labels.

```
> dim(d)
[1] 5664   17

> head(d)
      c_id event   c c_sh   d d_sh   e   f f_sh   g g_sh   a a_sh   b bass meter chord
1 000106b_     2 YES   NO  NO   NO YES  NO   NO YES   NO  NO   NO  NO    E     5   C_M
2 000106b_     3 YES   NO  NO   NO YES  NO   NO YES   NO  NO   NO  NO    E     2   C_M
3 000106b_     4 YES   NO  NO   NO  NO YES   NO  NO   NO YES   NO  NO    F     3   F_M
4 000106b_     5 YES   NO  NO   NO  NO YES   NO  NO   NO YES   NO  NO    F     2   F_M
5 000106b_     6  NO   NO YES   NO  NO YES   NO  NO   NO YES   NO  NO    D     4   D_m
6 000106b_     7  NO   NO YES   NO  NO YES   NO  NO   NO YES   NO  NO    D     2   D_m

> levels(e$chord)
  [1] " A#d"  " A#d7" " A_d"  " A_m"  " A_M"  " A_m4" " A_M4" " A_m6" " A_M6" " A_m7" " A_M7" " Abd"  " Abm" 
 [14] " AbM"  " B_d"  " B_d7" " B_m"  " B_M"  " B_M4" " B_m6" " B_m7" " B_M7" " Bbd"  " Bbm"  " BbM"  " Bbm6"
 [27] " BbM7" " C#d"  " C#d6" " C#d7" " C#m"  " C#M"  " C#M4" " C#m7" " C#M7" " C_d6" " C_d7" " C_m"  " C_M" 
 [40] " C_M4" " C_m6" " C_M6" " C_m7" " C_M7" " D#d"  " D#d6" " D#d7" " D#m"  " D#M"  " D_d7" " D_m"  " D_M" 
 [53] " D_M4" " D_m6" " D_M6" " D_m7" " D_M7" " Dbd"  " Dbd7" " Dbm"  " DbM"  " Dbm7" " DbM7" " E_d"  " E_m" 
 [66] " E_M"  " E_M4" " E_m6" " E_m7" " E_M7" " Ebd"  " EbM"  " EbM7" " F#d"  " F#d7" " F#m"  " F#M"  " F#M4"
 [79] " F#m6" " F#m7" " F#M7" " F_d"  " F_d7" " F_m"  " F_M"  " F_M4" " F_m6" " F_M6" " F_m7" " F_M7" " G#d" 
 [92] " G#d7" " G#m"  " G#M"  " G_d"  " G_m"  " G_M"  " G_M4" " G_m6" " G_M6" " G_m7" " G_M7"

> length(unique(e$chord))
[1] 102

> nrows_split_d # number of observations for each class label
  [1]   5   4   5 258 352   2  16  10   2  11  56   1   2  37  17   8 217 143   3   2  19  46   5  26 312   6
 [27]   3  10   2  15  24  39   2   9   7   2   2 144 488  16  17   6  20  66   7   1   4   2   2   4 165 503
 [53]  16  12   3  33  58   2   2   4  21   3   1   6 241 295  14  14  24  43   1 146   1  14   1 143  90  12
 [79]   7  19  34   3   1  42 388  14   3   4   7  38  11   6   6   1   3 179 489   8   3   3  18  52
>
```

I'm facing issues as a result of how some class labels have so few observations. When it comes to random sampling/ partitioning the data into train and test sets, I've been able to find a work-around, which negates some element of randomness; find a seed that enables the training set to have at least 1 of each of the 102 class labels. Given there are 5664 observations and the training set comprises of 70-80% of the data, this was easily achievable. Furthermore, it seems to work fine, whenever the algorithm I decide to use don't necessitate matrix input/ output.

When I try to feed this into a NN, the same strategy seemingly works, when it comes to create a confusion matrix though, I have issues, as the matrices have different dimensions and indices, as a result of missing unique labels within the test set.

Even when I reduce size of training set and sample with replacement, I'm unable to find a seed where both train and test sets contain 1 of each of the 102 class labels.

A potential solution I could attempt, is to introduce duplicate observations where the frequency of the class label is low. But I'm hesitant to do so, since that's basically cheating.

1) Am I "allowed"/ is it "good practice", to manipulate the seed in order to ensure that the training set contains 1 of each of the unique class labels?

2) Are there any solutions for this problem that don't involve seed manipulation/ introducing duplicates?

If I didn't ensure the 102 uniques in the training set, I wouldn't be able to pass the data to most algorithms as errors will be raised due to the discrepancy.

```
> length(unique(test$chord))
[1] 75
> length(unique(train$chord))
[1] 102

t <- table(predict=pre, actual=test_t)

> length(unique(pre))
[1] 62
> length(unique(test_t))
[1] 85

nn_accuracy <- sum(diag(t) / sum(t))
> nn_accuracy
[1] 0.4077125
```

Comment: With 12 binary columns and a column of 102 cords, has potentially over 400,000 different combinations yet your dataset is only contains 5660 observations.  Do you really expect a meaningful fit?  I would first consider if any of binary columns are strong correlated with each other and then potentially bin together some of the cords to reduce the number of unique combinations.

Comment: I got 92% accuracy on test data with xgboost and 85% with SVM. Also, oob accuracy while training was around 70% not the 40% I'm getting from the confusion matrix, which is why I suspect it's wrong, also there are missing columns. I expect a meaningful fit because of how music theory works. There are only 12 notes, a chord is typically a triad, so if c is 1, e is 1, g is 1, that chord can only be a C, it might be an inversion of C, but still C. Usually bass notes are the tonic. Just ran a spearman correlation and none of the features are correlated above 0.2, which is to be expected.

Comment: I would still proceed with caution and consider the chance of over fitting.  From your results from "nrows_split_d" many of the rows are in the low single digits and are not a part of the test set.

Comment: You could well be right, I tried xgboost again on a 60% split between train and test on a seed where there were 102 unique labels in train and 95 unique labels in the test set and after just 50 iterations still achieved 89% accuracy, I believe the accuracy would be higher with greater iterations. It's hard to say whether it's over-fitting or whether the test set just doesn't contain enough of the lower frequency labels to affect the accuracy drastically. The more common labels are obviously classifying correctly. What can I do, given this?

Comment: I'll go back to my original comment, can you bin some of the 102 chord categories to a smaller number.  You mentioned in your comment that c, e or g is the same as a C, maybe you can start there.

Comment: I can reduce 102 chord categories to 99 by converting en-harmonic equivalent scales. It's hard to reduce further, since some of the en-harmonic equivalents aren't a class to begin with, so converting them wouldn't reduce the number of uniques. Furthermore, when we get to diminished/ dominants/ 7ths, while the root may be an en-harmonic equivalent, the altered notes aren't. Since I'm concerned with the classification of chords, not which chorale they belong to, could I simply duplicate observations where the frequency of observations for that label is low?